# How do use function interfaces with callbacks with a return value

Tags: typescript

I'm experimenting with `TypeScript` and trying to wrap my head around how interfaces for functions work. I wrote a simple interface that optionally accepts a `Context` asserted object, so that it can be used both inside and outside a class context.

**Interface**

```
interface EHandler {
    (ctx?: Context): Context
}
```

**Function**

```
let testFn: EHandler = function(_ctx: Context): Context {
    // Do some work with the Context object
    return _ctx;
}(ctx)
```

In this case the linter notifies me that;

```
Type 'Context' is not assignable to type 'EHandler'.
```

**Class method**

I'm not sure if this is would be the correct way to do this, but this is how I've tried to do this inside a class definition

```
protected TestHandler: EHandler = (): Context => {
    // Do some work with the Context object which is now accessible with this
    return this.context;
}
```

**Class method that uses the above definitions**

```
protected use(method: string, handler: EHandler): void {
    this.middleware.use(method, handler);
}
```

**Trying it out**

```
this.use('delete', this.TestHandler());
```

This produces the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Context' is not assignable to parameter of type '<Context>() => EHandler'.
    Type 'Context' provides no match for the signature '<Context>(): EHandler'.
```

I'm having a hard time finding any working examples with proper return values. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

As an aside, is the way I'm applying the function interface correct? I initially believed it would be something as simple as this: `protected TestHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function interface is correctly defined, as far as I understand your requirements. The only thing to note is that you could have used a simple function signature as well.

```
type EHandler = (ctx?: Context) => Context
```

The problem when you call `use` is that you invoke the `TestHander` function. What you want to do is actually pass the function itself to `use` not the rezult of calling the function:

```
class Context { p: null }
    type EHandler = (ctx?: Context) => Context

class a {
    constructor() {
        this.use('delete', this.TestHandler); // ok 
    }
    private context: Context
    protected TestHandler: EHandler = (): Context => {
        // Do some work with the Context object which is now accessible with this
        return this.context;
    }

    protected use(method: string, handler: EHandler): void {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! That cleared it right up. I've been stuck on this for hours. Also figured out why the function definition outside of the class was giving me a hard time. Instead of `let ctx = Context;` I did a `let ctx: Context`.